# Deeplearning4j - Can not use UIServer in learning WordVectors?

Tags: java, deeplearning4j

Now, I am trying to learn GloVe using Deeplearning4j. The learning process itself is good progressing.

So, I would like to monitor this learning process with **UIServer** while referring to [this page](https://deeplearning4j.konduit.ai/deeplearning4j/how-to-guides/tuning-and-training/visualization). On this page, UIServer is enabled with the code shown below.

```
// Define model
MultiLayerConfiguration conf = new NeuralNetConfiguration.Builder()
    // omitted
    .build();
MultiLayerNetwork net = new MultiLayerNetwork(conf);

// Enable UIServer
UIServer uiServer = UIServer.getInstance();
StatsStorage statsStorage = new InMemoryStatsStorage();
uiServer.attach(statsStorage);
net.setListeners(new StatsListener(statsStorage));
```

However, since the **setListeners** method does not exist in the WordVectors interface including GloVe etc., it can not be monitored by a general method. Is there a good way to monitor with the GUI?

The current code is shown below.

```
// Define model
Glove glove = new Glove.Builder()
    // omitted
    .build();

/**** I wanted to enable UIServer on this line. ****/

// Start training
glove.fit();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These word models aren't exactly neural networks so they don't have a visualization for the training.